# GWT: DefaultHistorian vs Mapper Objects?

Tags: java, gwt

The GWT JavaDocs for the [PlaceHistoryHandler#DefaultHistorian](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryHandler.DefaultHistorian.html) are vague and cyclic:

> Default implementation of PlaceHistoryHandler.DefaultHistorian.

This doesn't really tell us what it is, or what it does!

Then we have the [PlaceHistoryMapper](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryMapper.html) and the [ActivityMapper](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/ActivityMapper.html) objects. My *understanding* is that the `PlaceHistoryMapper`'s job is to map URL tokens to `Place`, and that `ActivityMapper` maps those `Place`s to `Actvitity` implementations.

So I ask: if these two Mappers take care of binding a URL token to a specific `Activity`, then what role does the `DefaultHistorian` play in all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc is easy to correct at read time: `DefaultHistorian` is the default implementation of [`Historian`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceHistoryHandler.Historian.html).

To understand how they all play together, you first have to understand that places can work without *history*, and also without activities.

So, in the central place are *places*: `PlaceController` keeps a current `Place` (`getWhere`), which can be modified by `goTo` and broadcasts change events to an `EventBus`. Listeners can ask the user to confirm (`PlaceChangeRequestEvent`'s `setMessage`) through [`Delegate`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/place/shared/PlaceController.Delegate.html) (whose default implementation uses `Window.confirm`).

Built on top of `PlaceRequestChangeEvent` and `PlaceChangeEvent` are activities. You can have several `ActivityManager`s, each one with its `ActivityMapper` and a *display region*, displaying a different activity each for the same given/current place.

And on the other side, based on `goTo` and the above-mentioned events is *history*. `PlaceHistoryHandler` listens to events on both sides and either *updates the history* (through the `Historian`) or updates the places (through `PlaceController`'s `goTo`). The `PlaceHistoryMapper` maps between both worlds. The default implementation of the `Historian` (`DefaultHistorian`) uses `com.google.gwt.user.client.History` and `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window#addWindowClosingHandler`. You could provide your own implementation that [uses HTML5's `pushState` and `onpopstate`](https://gist.github.com/1883821) for instance.

See:

- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-places/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-places-part-ii/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/